# Disabling default alert that normally appears on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable the default confirm box that fires onSubmit. I have been trying for a while now with no success. This is what I tried...

My Markup

```
<form method="post" action="special.php" id="myForm" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you ready to submit this order?\n\n')"> 
    //input fields
</form>
```

My JavaScript

```
$('.excelDL').click(function(){
       $('#myForm').trigger('submit', function(e){
            window.alert = function() {}; //overwrite default alert
            $.post('mail.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {})                 
            e.preventDefault();
        });         
});
```

Comment: No because I need the dialog box to appear in all other instances, except when I use the trigger to the submit the form.

Comment: I have never seen a function passed to `.trigger`... and the docs don't mention it either... what does it do? If you just want to call a function to make the Ajax request, then it does not look like you need to call `.trigger` at all. Just call the function.

Comment: I need trigger to the submit the form because my ajax request uses the POST values from the form, in a different way than the default submit button.

Comment: You'll have a much easier time of this if you remove the inline callbacks and refactor to unobtrusive javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with you're not firing an alert, you're firing a confirm.  so change
window.alert = function() {}; 
to
window.confirm = function() {};

then move it outside the submit function so that it overwrites the native function before the submit happens.

Comment: @MHZ: I'm sure there is a better solution, but you have to make your question/code clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The confirm box appears because of the `onsubmit="return confirm(...)"` attribute on your `<form>`. If you remove that, the confirm dialog will not appear when you submit the form via JQuery.

If you need this confirmation to appear *except* when submit the form using your `$('#myForm').trigger(...)` code, then remove your `window.alert = function() {};` line and add the line `$('#myForm').submit(function(){ return true; });` before you call `.trigger()`. This will remove the `onsubmit` handler for the form before submitting it.

It's generally a bad idea to try to override the built in methods (like `confirm()`) it's a much better idea to just not call them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know. However, I need the dialog to NOT appear in this instance, where I am using the trigger to submit the form, and appear in all other instances... The dialog is important enough to where I cannot remove it altogether, I just need to disable it somehow in this instance only.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery docs don't mention that you can pass a function to `.trigger` as second parameter and I don't believe it actually works.

If you just want to make the Ajax request without triggering `.submit`, you can make the call directly

```
$.post('mail.php', $('#myForm').serialize(), function (data) {});
```

or trigger only event handlers bound with jQuery using [`.triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/). In both cases a native `submit` event won't generated and event handlers bound with other ways won't be triggered.

---

As others said, binding all event handlers with jQuery instead of using inline event handlers would improve the code as well.

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply. For some reason when I remove the trigger and make the click function call the post function directly: `$.post('mail.php', $('#myForm').serialize(), function (data) {});` this does not work. No errors either. Any idea why?

Comment: You mean the Ajax request is not sent? Or what does "does not work mean"? Did you check with the developer tools? Also, what click function are you talking about? You really should post a more complete example of your code.

Comment: Yes, ajax request is not being sent, and yes, I checked developer tools, and no errors. I used your suggestion, and replaced all my javascript code to:`$('.excelDL').click(function(){ $('#excel').val(2); $.post('mail.php', $("#myForm").serialize(), function (data) {}); });`  which does not work.

Comment: The reason your method does not work is because the $.post needs to be inside a submit function / submit trigger in order for it to work, it will **not** work when called directly.

Comment: @MHZ: No, that is not correct. It does not matter *where* you call the method from. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/kYMZN/. It would not make sense either, because Ajax has nothing to do with HTML forms. I cannot tell you why it does not work. I assume there is another error in your code, but there is not much to say with the information you have given.

Answer (score 0):

just take this out

```
   onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you ready to submit this order?\n\n')"
```

then you can manually decide when to use the alert in this function

```
    $('#myForm').trigger('submit', function(e){
        // cal the confirm here , or write your own pop up script that looks the way you want.

    });
```